# Log requests for a specific location

Tags: nginx, scripting, log-files

Have the same problem. Tried with named location, but i always get the same thing, access log created for specific location (/calendar) is empty, and logs are stored in general access log (/) in a location context.

If I remove `.+\.php$` part from a last location context I'm getting a raw view of the index.php file., because of `^~` modifier. Any advice how to log requests to a specific location?

```
#user  root;
worker_processes  1;

pid        /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    #default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {

    listen 80;
    server_name ip-address;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    access_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
            try_files $uri =404;

        }

        location ^~ /calendar/.+\.php$ {
            access_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/calendar.log;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could try "access_log on;", though this could be the default. On may be implied if you specify the access_log as you already have. Worth a shot though probably not the solution.

Comment: Tried that just before opening the thread, but I just the same result as before. access_log is is turned on by the default. But thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your configuration file.

The modifier `^~` is for prefix locations and not regex locations (despite the presence of a tilde). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

In order to give a regex location precedence over another regex location, it simply needs to appear first.

The location block needs to be complete. `nginx` will not take bits from one location and merge it with bits from another.

For example, this might work for you:

```
location ~ ^/calendar/.+\.php$ {
    access_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/calendar.log;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
} 
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Comment: You are right Richard, thank you for your help. Just on more think. Why do I need to add  `/.+\.php$` if I alreday have  `include fastcgi.conf` and  `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080` in the calendar location context?

Comment: The regex `^/calendar/.+\.php$` fully specifies a `.php` file which is residing below the `/calendar/` path. We only want to send `.php` files to `fastcgi`. A shorter regex may also work depending on what other types of file live below `/calendar/`. But `^/calendar/.+\.php$` is the more complete solution. (Notice I have added a missing `^` to my answer)